# Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Polyline' to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.IUIElement10'

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

**Disclaimer: This problem occurred in Win10 1809, Win10 1909 test passed**

I found a strange thing, I took a UIElement object (named `polyline1`) from Canvas.Children, The full name of this object is `Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Polyline`, when I use `(polyline1 as Polyline)?.ActualOffset` When I get the error mentioned in the title: *`Unable to cast object of type'Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Polyline' to type'Windows.UI.Xaml.IUIElement10'`*, even if I use `polyline1.ActualOffset` I will get the same error.

Here is part of the code:

**xml**

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas">
    <Polyline x:Name="polyline1" Points="0,0 140,0 140,60" />
    <Polyline x:Name="polyline2" Points="0,0 240,0 240,60" />
    ....
</Canvas>
```

**code**

```
try
{
    var polyline1 = canvas.Children.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType().Name == typeof(Polyline).Name);
    Debug.Write($"fullname: {polyline1.GetType().FullName}");
    Debug.Write($"is polyline: {polyline1 is Polyline}");
    Debug.Write($"as polyline: {polyline1 as Polyline}");
    Debug.Write($"as polyline.ActualOffset.X: {(polyline1 as Polyline)?.ActualOffset.X}")
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Debug.Write($"error: {ex}");
}
```

**Output**

```
fullname: Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Polyline
is polyline: True
as polyline: Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Polyline
error: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Polyline' to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.IUIElement10'.
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW_WinRT(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, IntPtr& ppTarget)
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement.get_ActualOffset()
```

Comment: Just because you change the questions words, doesn't mean your code is right... Its actually still wrong and wouldn't compile, please check your code and make sure you have pasted the *REAL* code

Comment: @TheGeneral Thank you very much for your reminder, I modified the question to make sure it is consistent with the real situation

Comment: You need to check again, `var polyline` and  `polyline1` if the first statement is not meant to be included in the question, you might want to delete it, as it confuses the question

Comment: @TheGeneral Sorry, i'm too careless, thanks again for your reminder

Comment: Polyline does not contains `ActualOffset` property in 1809 target version.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Thanks, Is there any other way that can be equivalent to ActualOffset?

Comment: I have posted the case reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any other way that can be equivalent to ActualOffset

Sure, you could use the [TransformToVisual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.transformtovisual?view=winrt-19041) method to get the position of this UIElement, relative to its parent.

```
 var ttv = polyline1.TransformToVisual(canvas);
 Point position = ttv.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
```